# How to populate the array using the RAND () and WHILE?

Tags: c

I need to create an array that is populated randomly, considering an element with a value of `1` that can traverse positions in the array. Starting with a value in the middle position and selecting random positions for the other terms, I want it to go through the array until it finds the value `1` in the array (it would look like a branch). I wrote the code from what I could think of, but after requesting the dimensions of the array the program hangs, I even thought it might be because of `while` conditions. Could someone help me with the resolution? Thank you!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int **Alocar_matrix(int m, int n) {           //function for allocation of memory
    int i, **v;
    //ponteiro para a matriz - pointer for matrix
    v = (int **)calloc(m, sizeof(int *));
    if (v == NULL) {
        printf("Erro: Memoria Insuficiente");  //just a error test
        return (NULL);
    }
    //alocacao das colunas da matriz
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++)  {
        v[i] = (int*)calloc(n, sizeof(int));
        if (v[i] == NULL) {
            printf("Erro: Memoria Insuficiente");
            return (NULL);
        }
    }
    return (v);                           //retorna o ponteiro para a matriz
}

int main() {
    int **matrix;
    int i, j, x, y, step, erro, size;
    erro = 0;

    FILE *dla_program;                     //save the data in dla_program.txt
    dla_program = fopen("dla.txt", "w");

    do {
        printf("Informe o tamanho da matriz quadrada desejada. Ela deve ser maior que 100!");
        // it's a information from the user: the size of the matrix
        scanf("%d", &size);
    } while ((size < 100) || (size > 500));

    if ((matrix = Alocar_matrix(size, size)) == NULL)
        erro = 1;
    if (erro) {
        printf("\n Falta de memoria! Saindo...\n");        //erro na alocacao      ---test of memory
        exit(1);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < size; j++)        //zerar a matrix    -- define zero value to inicialization
            matrix[i][j] = 0;
    }
    matrix[(size - 1) / 2][(size - 1) / 2] = 1;      //particula localizada no centro  ---allocation of memory

    x = size + 1;
    y = size + 1;
    do {
        while ((x >= size) || (y >= size)) {       // while generalizado
            while (1) {
                x = rand() % size;
                y = rand() % size;
                if (matrix[x-1][y] || matrix[x+1][y] || matrix[x][y-1] || matrix[x][y+1] || matrix[x][y] == 0)
                    //escolher uma posição aleatória que não seja vizinha do centro  -- a choice of random position
                    break;
            }

            if (rand() % 1 < 0.5)
                step = 1;                    //condicional para definir a direção do deslocamento  -- random movement
            else
                step = -1;

            while (matrix[x-1][y] + matrix[x+1][y] + matrix[x][y-1] + matrix[x][y+1] == 0 || (x < size) || (y < size)) {
                if (rand() % 1 < 0.5)
                    x += step;
                else
                    y += step;
            }                                //procurar um vizinho
            matrix[x][y] = 1;               //quando encontrar um vizinho dentro de "size"  declara na posicao da matrix o valor 1
        }
    } while (matrix[size-1][y] || matrix[x][size-1] || matrix[0][y] || matrix[x][0] != 0);

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        printf("\n");
        {
            for (j = 0; j < size; j++)
                fprintf(dla_program, "\t%d ", matrix[i][j]);
        }
        printf("Dados armazenados em dla.txt \n\n");            //data storage in dla.txt
        fclose(dla_program);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is is tagged C#?

Comment: Why don't you use a 2D array? You're making your life way too complicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your program has multiple problems:

- `rand() % 1` always evaluates to `0`, defeating the purpose of *randomisation*. Use `rand() % 2` or `rand() & 1` to get a random binary value.
- there is no need to intialize the matrix to `0` since you allocate the arrays with `calloc()`, which is a good idea.
- you should check the return value of `fopen()` to avoid undefined behavior if file creation failed.
- you should check the return value of `scanf()` to avoid undefined behavior or an endless loop on invalid input, such as from an empty file or with non numeric input.
- the `while(1)` nested loop tries to locate a free position adjacent to a taken position but you access offsets in the matrix that or potentially out of bounds, causing undefined behavior (segmentation fault on my system).
- in the following loop, it is unclear why you try random moves from that position to find a cell with the same characteristics, again without proper boundary tests.
- the outer loops continue with surprising conditions, but no proper boundary tests either.
- the output loop is broken:

  - the file is closed after the first row is written
  - rows should be followed by a newline, not preceded. With the current code, the output file does not end with a newline.

You should simplify the method drastically:

- start from the center cell, which by the way is `matrix[(size + 1) / 2][(size + 1) / 2]`,
- iterate:

  - set the cell
  - check if all boundary cells are taken: if so, exit the loop
  - choose a random direction among the available cells
  - loop
- print the path.

Here is the modified code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

// allocate an indirect matrix: an array of arrays of int
int **Alocar_matrix(int m, int n) {
    int i, **v;

    v = calloc(m, sizeof(*v));
    if (v != NULL) {
        for (i = 0; i < m; i++)  {
            v[i] = calloc(n, sizeof(*v[i]));
            if (v[i] == NULL) {
                // free the memory allocated so far and exit the loop
                while (i-- > 0) {
                    free(v[i]);
                }
                free(v);
                v = NULL;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if (v == NULL) {
        printf("Erro: Memoria Insuficiente");
    }
    return v;
}

int main() {
    int **matrix;
    int c, i, j, x, y, n, size, input_ok;
    FILE *dla_program;                     //save the data in dla_program.txt

    // choose a random seed
    srand(clock());

    dla_program = fopen("dla.txt", "w");
    if (dla_program == NULL) {
        printf("Cannot open output file dla.txt\n");
        return 1;
    }

    size = 100;
    input_ok = 0;
    while (!input_ok) {
        // get the matrix size from the user
        printf("Informe o tamanho da matriz quadrada desejada. Ela deve ser maior que 100! ");
        switch (scanf("%d", &size)) {
        case 1:
            if (size >= 100 && size <= 500) {
                input_ok = 1;
                break;
            }
            printf("invalid matrix size: %d\n", size);
            break;
        case 0:
            printf("invalid input\n");
            // consume pending input
            while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n')
                continue;
            break;
        default:
            printf("unexpected end of file\n");
            return 1;
        }
    }

    if ((matrix = Alocar_matrix(size, size)) == NULL) {
        //erro na alocacao --- allocation failure
        printf("\n Falta de memoria! Saindo...\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    //particula localizada no centro --- start from the center
    x = y = (size + 1) / 2;

    for (;;) {
        matrix[x][y] = 1;
        // count the number of free neighbours
        n = 0;
        if (x > 0 && matrix[x - 1][y] == 0)
            n++;
        if (x < size && matrix[x + 1][y] == 0)
            n++;
        if (y > 0 && matrix[x][y - 1] == 0)
            n++;
        if (y < size && matrix[x][y + 1] == 0)
            n++;
        if (n == 0) {
            // dead end
            break;
        }
        // choose a random direction
        n = rand() % n;
        if (x > 0 && matrix[x - 1][y] == 0 && n-- == 0)
            x--;
        else if (x < size && matrix[x + 1][y] == 0 && n-- == 0)
            x++;
        else if (y > 0 && matrix[x][y - 1] == 0 && n-- == 0)
            y--;
        else
            y++;
    }
    // display to the terminal
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < size; j++)
            putchar(" X"[matrix[i][j]]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < size; j++)
            fprintf(dla_program, "\t%d", matrix[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("Dados armazenados em dla.txt \n\n");            //data storage in dla.txt
    fclose(dla_program);

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
        free(matrix[i]);
    free(matrix);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm very grateful for your help. Now I could see with the help of others too, that my RAND didn't make sense. But they had some points of the code that you posted that do not make sense to me:
That way of expressing the middle term of the matrix: does it not only consider matrices of odd dimensions, since we have x = y = (size + 1) / 2?
for example, that 'for (;;)' what would that be?
Those if's with the sum of the 'n' also were strange to me, because I understood that it tests in the neighbors of the middle term of the matrix if there are values. But what is it increasing?

Comment: `for (;;)` is a C idiom equivalent to `while (1)`. The first phase in this loop computes the number of neighbours `n` that are free, ie whose matrix value is `0`. The neighbours are only tested if they are inside the matrix, avoiding the undefined behavior that probably caused your program to crash. `n = rand() % n` chooses a random value between `0` and `n-1`, ie selects one of the available neighbours at random, the next batch of tests determines which one is the `n-th`, and updated either `x` or `y` for this new position. If `n` is `0`, the path has reached a dead-end and the loop stops.

Answer (score 1):

Since rand() returns an integer this statement

```
if (rand () % 1 < 0.5)
```

makes no sense

try

```
if (rand() % 2 == 1)
```

for a 50:50 chance.

Comment: or `rand() & 1 == 1` (odd) to get rid of the modulo.

Comment: Thank you ! I was really losing the purpose of the random function!